# Laravel не могу использовать action

Tags: laravel, namespace, controller, route

Есть такой код:

```
    public function sendActivationMail() {
    $activationUrl = action(
        'UsersController@getActivate',
        array(
            'userId' => $this->id,
            'activationCode' => $this->activationCode,
        )
    );
}
```

Код вызываемого контроллера:

```
class UsersController extends Controller
{
public function getActivate($userId, $activationCode) {
    // Получаем указанного пользователя
    $user = User::find($userId);
    if (!$user) {
        return $this->getMessage("Неверная ссылка на активацию аккаунта.");
    }

    // Пытаемся его активировать с указанным кодом
    if ($user->activate($activationCode)) {
        // В случае успеха авторизовываем его
        \Auth::login($user);
        // И выводим сообщение об успехе
        return $this->getMessage("Аккаунт активирован", "/");
    }

    // В противном случае сообщаем об ошибке
    return $this->getMessage("Неверная ссылка на активацию аккаунта, либо учетная запись уже активирована.");
}
```

}

При попытке выполнения получаю ошибку:

> InvalidArgumentException in UrlGenerator.php line 558:
>   Action App\Http\Controllers\UsersController@getActivate not defined.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо прописать данный маршрут в `routes.php`

Судя по названию метода, вы придерживаетесь такого подхода:

```
Route::controller('users', 'UsersController');
```

В противном случае, запись могла бы выглядеть как-то так:

```
Route::get('users/activate', 'UsersController@getActivate');
```

Собственно, причину исключения можно легко увидеть из кода `UrlGenerator::action()`:

```
if (! is_null($route = $this->routes->getByAction($action))) {
    return $this->toRoute($route, $parameters, $absolute);
}

throw new InvalidArgumentException("Action {$action} not defined.");
```